# How to fix navigation interference with image viewing in Windows 10 Photos?

Tags: windows-10, windows-photo-viewer

Navigation in the Photos App on Windows 10 covers the bottom of the image and is rather persistent in staying there, preventing you from seeing the full image content.

Additionally, there's a top-bar which does the same, but on the top of the picture.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Whoever thought this would be good app design should be made to read text from top and bottom of images using the app he made/approved. For a full year.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you go into Fullscreen slideshow mode, the overlap will fade out after a few seconds when nothing happens. The arrow keys will not bring them back, but the window is full screen.

If you want the same effect in a smaller window, there is a bug present in the viewer you can abuse.

Click on the arrows at the bottom right corner. When it goes full-screen, wait for the image to properly show, then press escape to exit full-screen mode. The controls remain hidden until you click inside the window.

Alternatively, you could download an actual image slideshow program.

Comment: Never thought I'd see the day when a bug is actually a feature.

Answer (score 7):

Spacebar hides the toolbar and its state is remembered between newly opened viewer windows. Not sure about if it will reset after computer restart, though.

Comment: This is it! I was really close to download another program so I could see pictures without that huge bar covering a part of them. Thank you!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @AustinDean Although this is correct now, it didn't work when the question was asked. Microsoft fixed a bug in the meanwhile.

Comment: This hides the toolbar at the top, but not the stupid menu on the bottom of the viewer, which is what the question is referring to.

Answer (score 1):

Click inside the window. This will hide the menu bar and a short time after the mouse pointer leaves the window, also the navigation will disapear.

Comment: Should be the correct answer.  Perhaps combined with the next one.  The accepted answer does NOT solve the problem (you should never have to use full-screen).

Answer (score -2):

Click the edit button on the top bar to hide the bottom navigation bar - you can take a screen grab now without the navigation bar.

To go back, click the top left back arrow for the photo navigation mode.